# Java Launch fails on second run: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I downloaded the .jnlp file and ran it. It runs fine. I close it and start it again, it runs fine.

However on the third try, it always throws java.lang.NullPointerException and the application will not launch.

If I restart the computer it works again. How can I fix this ?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.overlapSigners(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.getCertificates(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: hard to say, post the code...

Comment: Apparently it's a signing issue?

Comment: I think your application is not terminating properly. When you close your application it still running. You can share your piece of code..

Comment: program doesn't show up in task manager and neither does java.exe

Comment: I hate saying this, but, can you perhaps try to just reinstall the JRE and see if this persists?

Answer (score 5):

The stacktrace is the same as in [Bug ID 6533653](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6533653) and [Bug ID 6850598](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6850598). The root cause seems to be an empty JAR in JNLP. They said to have fixed it in Java 1.6 update 2 and Java 1.6 update 18 respectively.

However, there is a comment in the last bug which complains that the fix still doesn't work in 1.6 update 18, along with a description which look much like your situation:

> In vm 6u18 this bug is NOT closed. **You can launch your application once but after you have the following exception** :
>
> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> ```

```
    at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.overlapSigners(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.getCertificates(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

> **If I remove the empty jar from jnlp, all is ok.**
> Please verify your correction before publication

So, try removing the empty JAR from the JNLP and report it to the JNLP authors as well.

Comment: which is the empty jar ? As far as I know all of them are at least 2KB in size.

Answer (score 1):

We saw this issue as well for users with version 1.6.0_18.

I took a look at the jars listed in my jnlp file and found a license jar jumped out as a likely candidate for a jar with no classes.  I confirmed this with `jar tf`.

As a quick test I removed the jar from the jnlp file and I did not get the error.  However, I needed the license jar for a 3rd party library.

I updated my build file to bundle the license jar into my application jar

```
<jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/${application}.jar">
    <zipgroupfileset dir="${extLib}" includes="runtime.jar" />
...
</jar>
```

The 3rd party library could locate the license info in the classpath and no more errors!

Comment: I tried this and found some of my jars weren't in the folder at all, so try an `ls *.jar` too.